# How to install website on clients system build in asp .net 4.0 having no .net framework

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have created a web application using asp .net 4.0, Now client wants to run this application on his local system. What are the pre requirements I need to apply to host application into his local IIS.

Answer (score 0):

If he doesn't have .net on his local machine, I think the only other option is to publish the application to a web server and have him access it through a browser, at least I haven't found another way and this was always the easiest option for me.

Comment: There is no problem in istalling .net framework I just want to know. Whether I have to install Visual studio or only .net frame work. Also is any other software required except database.